# how to display output of spark java application in UI

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-2.0

I have a Spark Java application for log mining. Currently I am reading the output from spark output files and displaying it in Excel Sheet. But I want a better UI. Can somebody help me to code a better UI for easier and better way to analyze the results of spark output. It will be helpful if I add graphs and table views.

Comment: I think you should take a look to apache zeppelin it will solve your problem and has interpreter for spark

Comment: Thanks Sachin. Let me google about it

Comment: Please remove the tag [spark-java]( which is entirely different framework). So that people like me don't stumble upon this thinking this as a Spak java framework question

Answer (score 0):

One option is exposing Spark data via JDBC/ODBC as described in:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#distributed-sql-engine

So you can write an Application for a platform of your choice.